# Synchronizing N process only with signals

Tags: c, unix, signals, system-calls

I'm doing an exercise for the course on Operating Systems. To learn to use signals (one of my weak points) I wanted to try to synchronize N processes only with signals. But I can't make it.

The code is:

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <signal.h>

// first sigHandler
void sigHandler(int signum)
{    
    printf("Received signal\n");
}

// second sigHandler
void sigHandler2(int signum)
{
    printf("Received other signal\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Number of process
    int N = 2;

    // Assign sigHandlers
    signal(SIGUSR1, sigHandler);
    signal(SIGUSR2, sigHandler2);

    // array for pids to activate in order;
    pid_t pid[N];

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // creation child
        pid[i] = fork();

        if (pid == 0)
        {
            // if is the last child, resume the father
            if (i == N - 1)
            {
                kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
            }

            // expect SIGUSR1
            pause();
            printf("%i completed\n", getpid());
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    // expext that all child started
    pause();

    // active the last child
    i--;
    kill(pid[i], SIGUSR1);
    signal(SIGUSR1, sigHandler);

    // active other child
    while (wait(NULL) != -1)
    {
        i--;
        kill(pid[i], SIGUSR1);
        signal(SIGUSR1, sigHandler);
    }
    printf("All fine\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

I tried to replace `pause()` system with `sleep(10)`, but the result was four "All fine" messages on the terminal.

I suppose that the problem derives from the asynchronous nature of signals, but I don't understand how to resolve it.

Comment: Note the guidelines in the answers to [How to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16891019/15168)  In practice, it is not a part of your problem, but you should be aware of the rules.

Answer (score 0):

A major part of the problem is the test `if (pid == 0)` — the array address is not null.  You meant `if (pid[i] == 0)`!

With that change and the minimal changes necessary to get the code to compile under my default compilation options (which are fairly fussy), I get this output from the program `sig79`:

```
$ sig79
Received other signal
Received signal
15312 completed
Received signal
15311 completed
All fine
$
```

While debugging the problem, I used this code, which has copious printing (partly because I was confused by the flawed test).  I use a waiting loop because there are circumstances under which your parent process could have children it doesn't create — obscure circumstances, but this code accounts for those.  Note that the children exit with a status corresponding to the child number; you can see those numbers in the reported exit status in the waiting loop.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void write_msg(size_t len, char *msg)
{
    int pid = getpid();
    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
    {
        msg[i-1] = pid % 10 + '0';
        pid /= 10;
    }
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, len);
}

// first sigHandler
static void sigHandler1(int signum)
{    
    assert(signum == SIGUSR1);
    static char msg[] = "XXXXX: Received signal SIGUSR1\n";
    write_msg(sizeof(msg) - 1, msg);
}

// second sigHandler
static void sigHandler2(int signum)
{
    assert(signum == SIGUSR2);
    static char msg[] = "XXXXX: Received signal SIGUSR2\n";
    write_msg(sizeof(msg) - 1, msg);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Number of process
    int N = 2;

    // Assign sigHandlers
    signal(SIGUSR1, sigHandler1);
    signal(SIGUSR2, sigHandler2);

    printf("%d: parent at work\n", getpid());

    // array for pids to activate in order;
    pid_t pid[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // creation child
        pid[i] = fork();

        if (pid[i] == 0)
        {
            printf("%d: child %d at play\n", getpid(), i+1);
            // if is the last child, resume the father
            if (i == N - 1)
            {
                kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
                printf("%d: signal SIGUSR2 sent to PID %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
            }

            // expect SIGUSR1
            pause();
            printf("%d: child %d completed\n", getpid(), i+1);
            exit(i+1);
        }
        printf("%d: child %d has PID %d\n", getpid(), i+1, pid[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    // expect that all children started
    pause();

    for (int i = N; i > 0; i--)
    {
        kill(pid[i - 1], SIGUSR1);
        printf("%d: signal SIGUSR1 sent to child %d PID %d\n", getpid(), i, pid[i - 1]);
        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        {
            if (corpse == pid[i - 1])
            {
                printf("%d: child %d PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
                       getpid(), i, corpse, status);
                break;
            }
            else
                printf("%d: unexpected child PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
                       getpid(), corpse, status);
        }
    }

    printf("%d: All fine\n", getpid());
    return(0);
}
```

One time when I ran the program (`sig59`), I got the output:

```
$ sig59
15177: parent at work
15177: child 1 has PID 15178
15178: child 1 at play
15177: child 2 has PID 15179
15179: child 2 at play
15179: signal SIGUSR2 sent to PID 15177
15177: Received signal SIGUSR2
15177: signal SIGUSR1 sent to child 2 PID 15179
15179: Received signal SIGUSR1
15179: child 2 completed
15177: child 2 PID 15179 exited with status 0x0200
15177: signal SIGUSR1 sent to child 1 PID 15178
15178: Received signal SIGUSR1
15178: child 1 completed
15177: child 1 PID 15178 exited with status 0x0100
15177: All fine
$
```

And, to demonstrate that the obscure circumstances can occur:

```
$ forker -s 0 -c 'exit 37' -- ./sig59
forker: Setting number of child processes to 3
15138: forker at work
15138: launched 15139
15138: launched 15140
15138: launched 15141
15138: executing ./sig59
15138: parent at work
15138: child 1 has PID 15142
15138: child 2 has PID 15143
15142: child 1 at play
15143: child 2 at play
15143: signal SIGUSR2 sent to PID 15138
15138: Received signal SIGUSR2
15138: signal SIGUSR1 sent to child 2 PID 15143
15143: Received signal SIGUSR1
15143: child 2 completed
15138: child 2 PID 15143 exited with status 0x0200
15138: signal SIGUSR1 sent to child 1 PID 15142
15138: unexpected child PID 15139 exited with status 0x2500
15142: Received signal SIGUSR1
15142: child 1 completed
15138: unexpected child PID 15140 exited with status 0x2500
15138: unexpected child PID 15141 exited with status 0x2500
15138: child 1 PID 15142 exited with status 0x0100
15138: All fine
$
```

The `forker` program ran three processes each of which in turn ran `exit 37` (hex 0x25) and then executed the `sig59` process (which had no clue that it had children from its previous life as the `forker` process).

Comment: Thanks. The problem was the pid==0. This remained from a previous version of the exercise, and I didn't change because I am air-headed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It caught me by surprise, but I was compiling on a machine with a somewhat older version of GCC (8.3.0) than I use at work.  The `-Waddress` option (implied by `-Wall`) didn't report that the code was checking an array address against null.  The compilers I use at work (11.2.0, 12.1.0, etc) do report such comparisons, GCC 12.1.0 more copiously (but accurately) than older versions.